# Cross referencing Pandas Dataframes with multiple occurrences of right key on left Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames, A and B. A has a column which is "B_id", B has a "ID" column. However, many rows on A use the same "B_id" to determine data about that row which repeats. For example, A looks like this:

```py
A:
ID    Name    (...)    B_id
1     John     ...     123
2     Emily    ...     123
3     Erick    ...     321
```

Where B could look like this:

```py
B:
ID     Model  (...)
123    M1      ...
321    M2      ...
```

What I want is to create a new Dataframe combine and cross referencing the information from both DataFrames, where all columns for the corresponding B_id would be added to the row in A. The output would look like this:

```py
Result:
ID    Name    (...)    B_id    Model    (...)
1     John     ...     123     M1        ...
2     Emily    ...     123     M1        ...
3     Erick    ...     321     M2        ...
```

I've tried with `pd.merge` with 'left' as `how`, but it returns a empty DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. What you need to do is specify the column on which to merge using the `on` parameter in pandas' `merge`  method (`on=B_id`). In order for this to work, you must first ensure that the column to join on shares the same name in both dataframes. You may either:

- rename column `ID` to `B_id` in the B dataframe: `dfB.rename(columns={"ID": "B_id"}`
- or simply create a new column with that name: `dfB['B_id'] = dfB['ID']`.

Here is a code example:

```
import pandas as pd

dfA = pd.DataFrame()
dfA['ID'] = [1, 2, 3]
dfA['Name'] = ['John', 'Emily', 'Erick']
dfA['B_id'] = [123, 123, 321]

dfB = pd.DataFrame()
dfB['ID'] = [123, 321]
dfB['Model'] = ['M1', 'M2']

dfB['B_id'] = dfB['ID']

pd.merge(df1,df2, on='B_id')
```

This returns:

```
    ID_x    Name    B_id    ID_y    Model
0   1   John    123     123     M1
1   2   Emily   123     123     M1
2   3   Erick   321     321     M2
```